# Swift : UILabel nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I have a Struct which contains information about checking out books. When a user deletes or adds books I use the did set method in order to count the total number of books in the array and then set the total to a label I have in another class. The problem is when I try to set the number to the label I keep getting a "nill while unwrapping an optional value" I checked other questions posted here and try to fix this issue but I can't fix I am not sure if I am doing somthing wrong or maybe my story board is set up wrong

ViewController which hold the struct and the array and using didSet to monitor the changes in the array

```
 let NewLabel = ViewControllerExtension()
 var ServiceReportArray = [ServiceReport](){
    didSet{
            let sum : [Int] = ServiceReportArray.map{return$0.NumberOfBooks}
            let totalSum = sum.reduce(0){return $0 + $1}
            NewLabel.BooksLabel.text = String(totalSum)

            //NewLabel.Myreload()
            // This function returns the same error
  }
}
```

This is the class where my label is at and created the Myreload() function to be called instead of just putting the information from the didSet but still get the error.

```
class ViewControllerExtension : UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var BooksLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
func Myreload(){
    let sum : [Int] = ServiceReportArray.map{return $0.NumberOfBooks}
    let totalSum = sum.reduce(0){return $0 + $1}
    BooksLabel.text = String(totalSum)

  }  
}
```

Comment: try with UILabel?

Comment: @NaumanMalik tried it already doesn't work is it maybe because i have the view controller inside another view controller using a container view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i figured what was wrong. First my View Controller was inside another view controller using a container view( this was the problem). To fix this i went ahead and gave the Container View an Identifier( as shown below)
[ViewController ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLb53.png)

Next I went to my ViewController and added this and accessed the CreateMyLabel function and it worked perfectly.

```
var embeddedViewController : MyCustomeTotalCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       self.embeddedViewController.CreateMyLabel()
}



 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? MyCustomeTotalCell,
        segue.identifier == "TotalReport"{ self.embeddedViewController = vc
           }
 }
```

The problem was that i needed to use a segue since it was embedded into the view controller. Hope this helps anyone that has this same issue. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are creating your `NewLabel` variable by just creating a `UIViewController` object. The `@IBOutlet` is linked to a storyboard element, and since you are not creating it from a storyboard, the `BooksLabel` is `nil`.

**What I suggest**

Create a subclass of `UIViewController` (instead of just an extension). (If the extensions are working for you, you don't need this, but that's what I do)

Then, initialize your view controller as follows:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboard_name", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sb_identifier") as! YourViewControllerClass
```

First you need to set an identifier for your view controller in the storyboard.

[image: sbid]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Just tried it but now I'm getting "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is

First confirm the order of the code, whether it was initialized to execute didSet, the order of the implementation of the program

Followed by the detection of ViewControllerExtension in your StoryBoard settings, the associated class is correct, whether there is redundant connection

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting to the root view controller of your app you can do:

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController as? ViewControllerExtension
viewController.BooksLabel.text = String(totalSum)
```

But if you are applying on the first child view controller(`childViewControllers[0]`), second child view controllers(`childViewControllers[1]`), then you can use below :

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.childViewControllers[0] as? ViewControllerExtension
viewController.BooksLabel.text = String(totalSum)
```

*This is an alternative solution but not the best.

Comment: Okay will try. The thing is my view controller is inside another view controller and i am using a container view and embedded the view controller their so I'm not sure if thats why it is not working